# Converting Negative Decimal to Hex

Tags: exploit

I came through [a post on Offensive Security](http://www.offensive-security.com/vulndev/quickzip-stack-bof-0day-a-box-of-chocolates/#prettyPhoto) and while reading , the author stated that:

> At next SEH (when using a SE Handler address that starts with a null byte), we usually will put some code to jump back.   After all, the null byte would acts as a string terminator and it does not make sense to put something after the SE Handler address (after all, you would not be able to jump to it anyway, right ?)
>
> Typically, in a scenario like this, we want to do a short jump back… this jumpback opcode looks like this :xebxf0xffxff  (so basically, jump back 10 bytes)

So, as per my understanding, to jmp back, I have to convert the decimal value to hex (I am using this `[printf "%x\n" -7]` in my shell as a quick way to convert -7 to hex) then add this value to the `jmp` instruction `\xeb`.

I have 2 questions here:

1-the final format of the opcode should be `\xeb\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD` (the jump instruction `\xeb` followed by 4 bytes), however, the author includes only 3 bytes after `\xeb` ? is there is a missing `\xff`?

2-the author states that `\xeb\xf0\xff\xff` jumps back 10 bytes, however, I converted it myself and found that jumping back 10 bytes should be `\xeb\xf6\xff\xff` instead of `\xeb\xf0\xff\xff` which jumps back 16 bytes ?

Comment: Since it's a short jump the code should be `EB` followed by one byte. If I remember correctly those jump offsets are relative to the *end* of the jump instruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several jump opcodes; see the Intel manuals. I recommend the [original 80386 manual](http://microsym.com/editor/assets/386intel.pdf) which talks only about the 32-bit 80386, thus omitting all the extra features of ulterior CPU: this will make for a much easier, *shorter* read.

Go page 319 of that manual: you will see that, at the machine code level, there are no less than *21* distinct jump opcodes. The one which begins with `EB` is a short jump, followed by a single byte, thus allowing for a jump range of -128 to +127 bytes. The displacement is counted from the byte which immediately *follows* the whole instruction (the first byte *after* the one-byte displacement parameter), so `EB 00` is a no-operation: it jumps to the instruction which follows the jump, where it would have gone anyway if there had been no jump. Similarly, `EB FE` is an infinite loop (jump back to itself). `EB F0` jumps back 16 bytes, hence 14 bytes before the `EB` byte.

<sup>**Note:** be wary about the 16-bit/32-bit duality of x86 processors. All modern operating systems run in 32-bit mode. This changes nothing for the "short jump" we are talking about here, but it alters "near jumps" which will take a 32-bit displacement offset in 32-bit mode.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies the picture here. just to make sure that I grasp it correctly. This means that \xeb\xf0\xff\xff will not jump back 10 bytes as the author stated, it should be \xeb\xf4\xff\xff which means a total displacement of -12 and -10 from the EB byte ? right ?                                                                   Also, can I remove these FF as its useless ?

Comment: Well, yes. That's what the manuals say. I have not read the article you link to, so I cannot truthfully comment on it.